# ASP.NET JWT Bearer i cant get User Data to my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jwt

I want to learn how to work with JWT Bearer, but I don't know if I have set it up correctly
My settings:

```
`
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidateAudience = true,
ValidateLifetime = true,
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
ValidIssuer = "meuf", // Замініть це на свої значення
ValidAudience = "meufCorporation", // Замініть це на свої значення
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")) // Замініть це на свої значення
};
}).AddCookie(options =\>
{
options.Cookie.Name = "Cookies";
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
// Отримати токен з заголовка або запиту
string token = context.Request.Headers\["Authorization"\];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && token.StartsWith("Bearer "))
    {
        // Видалити "Bearer " з рядка токену
        token = token.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
    
        // Перевірка і розшифрування токену
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
        };
    
        try
        {
            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
    
            if (principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
            {
                // Отримати всі клейми з токену
                var claims = identity.Claims.ToList();
    
                // Створити клейм "name" зі значенням ідентифікатора користувача та додати його до клеймів
                var userIdClaim = new Claim("name", principal.Identity.Name);
                claims.Add(userIdClaim);
    
                // Створити новий ClaimsIdentity з оновленими клеймами
                var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, identity.AuthenticationType, identity.NameClaimType, identity.RoleClaimType);
    
                // Встановити новий ClaimsIdentity для поточного користувача
                context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Обробити помилку при розшифруванні або перевірці токену
            Console.WriteLine($"Token validation error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    
    await next();

});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();`
```

And Controller

```
` [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                return View(); // Обробка випадку, коли користувач не аутентифікований або відсутній ідентифікатор користувача
            }

            if (Guid.TryParse(userId, out Guid currentUserId))
            {
                var currentUser = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(currentUserId);
                if (currentUser == null)
                {
                    return NotFound(); // Обробка випадку, коли користувача не знайдено
                }

                ViewData["Username"] = currentUser.UserName;
                ViewData["Email"] = currentUser.Email;

                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View(); // Обробка випадку, коли значення "id" не може бути перетворене на Guid
            }
        }`
```

I wanted to get data from the user, but I can't get it in the profile with registration, everything is fine, I don't know if it's an error in the project settings or in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is check JWT token you are sending in the Authorization header.

Check the token's contents & expiration in https://jwt.io/ and make sure your signing key was used for it's generation.